# Can't figure out how to return the proper amount of even numbers in the array

Tags: arrays, pointers

Whenever I run this, it ends up giving me the number of objects in the array. I'm new to the whole pointer thing and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I need it to display the amount of even numbers in the given array, not the amount of numbers all together in the array. Thanks!!! :)

```
 int counteven(int *a, int size)
//reserves space for the pointer of a certain size
{   int b;
int c=0;
for (b=0; b<size; b++)
{
    if (a[b]%2==0); 
    //if the remainder is 0 when dividing by 2 add
    //1 to the amount of even numbers
    {
        c++;
    }
}
return c;
}
int main () 
try {

int *a, b=0, c, e;
cout << "\n Please enter how many numbers you have: ";
//displays instructions
scanf("%d", &c);
a=(int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
//allocates a block the size of the int
for(b=0; b<c; b++)
    {
        printf( "Please enter a[%d]: " , b+1);
        //prompts the user to enter the first, second, third and
        //so on number that they want to determine whether or not
        //is even
        scanf("%d", (a+b));
    }
    for (b=0;b<c;b++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=%d \n", b+1, *(a+b));
    }
    e=counteven(a,c);
    cout << endl << "The total amount of even numbers is " << c << endl;
    return 0;

}
catch (...) {
cout << "Exception occurred" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (a[b]%2==0);`

Drop the semicolon here: you want the following block to depend on the result of the condition, but the semicolon ends the statement right there.

`cout << endl << "The total amount of even numbers is " << c << endl;`

Here I think you meant `e`, not `c`. You want to display the value `counteven` returned in the preceding line, not the total.

With both these changes, your sample works.

Comment: ahhh thank you!!! such a small thing leads to such a big mistake in coding lol thank you :)